# ToJSON method not found - which namespace is required?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, nlog

I want to log .net WEB API request-response to newly created file. So, I have implemented NLog mechanism in my project which works great. but still below code's .ToJSON() line doesn't get resolved. I can't figure out which namespace is required to use it. is there anything missing out?

I'm referring these two articles but still can't figure out.

1)  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1028416/RESTful-Day-sharp-Request-logging-and-Exception-ha

2) http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-nlog-to-provide-custom-tracing-for-your-asp-net-web-api/

.net namespaces

```
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Tracing;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
```

---

```
     if (level != TraceLevel.Off)
            {
                if (traceAction != null && traceAction.Target != null)
                {
                    category = category + Environment.NewLine + "Action     Parameters : " + traceAction.Target.ToJSON();  //this ToJSON doesn't get resolved. which namespace should I include? 
                }
                var record = new TraceRecord(request, category, level);
                if (traceAction != null) traceAction(record);
                Log(record);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such method. The example from [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1028416/RESTful-Day-sharp-Request-logging-and-Exception-ha#_Toc429234273) shows you how to make it yourself:

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;


namespace WebApi.Helpers
{
    public static class JSONHelper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Extened method of object class, Converts an object to a json string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ToJSON(this object obj)
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            try
            {
                return serializer.Serialize(obj);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Web.Script.Serialization; how can i add it?

Comment: Read the codeproject website. ... add "System.Web.Extensions.dll" reference to project...

Comment: traceAction.Target.ToJSON()... now it works fine. but when it writes almost   [{}] to file because when I put my cursor on Target at run time while debugging it, it gives me exp messageArguments {object1}. it contains required data in zeroth element. but i cant access it. is there any way to get it?

Comment: Or if you already use json.net - return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use JSON.Net. It is most likely already referenced in your project and `System.Web.Extensions.dll` is ancient nowadays (its [performance is terrible](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159450/fastJSON)):

```
public void Trace(HttpRequestMessage request, string category, TraceLevel level, Action<TraceRecord> traceAction)
{
    if (level != TraceLevel.Off)
    {
        if (traceAction != null && traceAction.Target != null)
        {
            category = category + Environment.NewLine + "Action Parameters : " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(traceAction.Target);
        }
        var record = new TraceRecord(request, category, level);
        if (traceAction != null) traceAction(record);
        Log(record);
    }
}
```